# Communication between background scripts and content script in a loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, promise, synchronous, sendmessage

I'm developing a Chrome extension that:

- opens a "panel" with a button
- when you click the button, a new tab is created
- then in this new tab, I loop through an array of URLs to retrieve information on each URL

For these actions, I'm using Promises, because I think it's the way to do.

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    var tabUrl = tab.url;
    originalWindowId = tab.windowId;
    var popupURL = chrome.runtime.getURL("extension/main_panel.html");
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: popupURL,
        type: 'panel',
        width: 600,
        height: 520
    }, function (window) {
        extensionWindowId = window.id;
    });
});

function createNewTab() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: "about:blank"
        }, function (tab) {
            console.log("tab created with id " + tab.id);
            resolve(tab.id);
        });
    });
}

function updateNewTab(newTabId, url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        chrome.tabs.update(newTabId, {
            url: url
        }, function (tab) {
            console.log("tab with id " + tab.id + " updated");
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
                if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
                    console.log("tab with id " + tab.id + " and url " + url + " updated complete");
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
                        action: "getATitle"
                    }, function (response) {
                        if (response.data != "") {
                            resolve(response.data);
                        } else
                            reject("failed");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**main_panel.js**

```
var urls = ["https://forum.openstreetmap.fr/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6811&start=0", "https://forum.openstreetmap.fr/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6811&start=25"];
const j = urls.length;

var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

var scrapButton = document.getElementById("scrap_button");
scrapButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    background.
    createNewTab()
        .then(function (newTabId) {
            console.log("response : newTabId " + newTabId);
            var all = []; 
            for (let i = 0; i < j; i ++) {
                console.log("try with i = " + i + " | url = " + urls[i]);
                var p = background.updateNewTab(newTabId, urls[i]);
                all.push(p);
            }
            return Promise.all(all);
        })
        .then(function (values) {
            console.log(values);
        })

});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("request from bg : " + request.action + " | url = " + location.href);
        if (request.action == "getATitle") {
            var title = $("h3.first a").text();
            console.log("title = " + title);
            sendResponse({
                data: title
            });
        }
    }
);
```

So my problem is that I retrieve twice the result from the second URL, not from the first. I think it's a (a)synchronous issue but which one?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

So thanks to wOxxOm who drove me on the right way !

But it's still not totally ok : I success to retrieve information on each URL, one after one, and from the "panel" side, all is fine.

But in background side, after it received response from content side for the first URL, it updates the tab with second URL, but chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener send the message 2 times, one with the first URL, one with the second, and in response, content send 2 times its information.
I think of a listener problem : maybe I have to remove it after each update ?

I don't know if I am very clear... Here's a picture of console:

[image: console log of background.js]

And here's the new code of main_panel.js

```
var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

var scrapButton = document.getElementById("scrap_button");
scrapButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    background.
    createNewTab()
        .then(function (newTabId) {
            console.log("response : newTabId " + newTabId);
            return processUrls(newTabId);
        })
});

async function delayedUpdate(newTabId, url, response) {
    const data = await background.updateNewTab(newTabId, url);
    console.log("data : " + data);
}

async function processUrls(newTabId) {
    for (const url of urls) {
        console.log("try with url = " + url);
        await delayedUpdate(newTabId, url);
    }
    console.log('Done!');
}
```

**EDIT 2**

So thanks to wOxxOm who helped me to accomplish the final code for background.js:

```
function updateNewTab(newTabId, url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        chrome.tabs.update(newTabId, {
            url: url
        }, function (tab) {
            console.log("tab with id " + tab.id + " updated");
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function tabUpdatedListener(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
                if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
                    console.log("tab with id " + tab.id + " and url " + url + " updated complete");
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
                        action: "getATitle"
                    }, function (response) {
                        console.log("data received in bg : " + response.data);
                        if (response.data != "") {
                            resolve(response.data);
                 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(tabUpdatedListener);
                        } else
                            reject("failed");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It's `var p = background.updateNewTab` - this doesn't return the result into your p variable. Instead, it enqueues a Promise which runs later, when the entire current function completes. The easiest solution is to switch to async/await syntax.

Comment: I've edited my question : can you have a look please ?

Comment: Yes all the old listeners will trigger and mess up your workflow. The easiest solution is to add a name after `function` keyword and invoke chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener when you are about to resolve/reject.

Comment: just perfect ! many thanks wOxxOm ! I post the final resolution !